# Adding a Check Constraint in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, check-constraints

For below table,

How to add a Constraint in SQL to enforce a maximum of one AddressID has Primary = TRUE where EndDate = 12/31/9999 ?

[image]

Comment: Can there be a duplicate of PK 7 with AddressId=102, Primary=FALSE, EndDate = 12/31/9999?

Comment: Yes there can be duplicates with different PK

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a unique constraint on the 3 columns: AddressID, Primary, EndDate.

```
ALTER TABLE [YourTableName]
ADD CONSTRAINT [UniqueConstraintName] UNIQUE (AddressID, Primary, EndDate);
```

Comment: In that case I can not have multiple FALSE. I should be able to have multiple FALSE

Comment: Also, as I stated in my question, only for EndDate 12/31/9999  I should restrict it to having 1 TRUE

Comment: Please provide more examples what what values are acceptable in the table.

Comment: Updated the question with more values

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is a unique index, not a constraint; an index can be filtered, though a constraint cannot. Please try the index creation script below and let me know how it goes.
Another point, you have a field named PRIMARY which is a reserved word in SQL Server; while you are able to circumvent syntactical issues by enclosing the field name in square brackets (as I did in the index script below) you would want to try to avoid that naming convention if at all possible.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_max_address_id
ON myTable (PK, AddressId)
WHERE [PRIMARY] = 'TRUE'
AND EndDate = '12/31/9999'
```